# Appendix page renders off-center

Tags: appendices

I'm currently writing a document with a large number of images in the appendix and I've encountered a hiccup. As I begin the first appendix section to include figures, the first page renders of center for some reason. See the image below:

[image: Appendix]

Also, notice how the page numbering skips this off-center page. Here is the code for my appendix:

```
    \appendix
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}
    {\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Appendix}
    \setcounter{equation}{0}

    %%% Appendix A goes here %%%%

    \chapter{Fit Images}

    %%% Large amount of text here %%%

    \section{Single Gaussian Fits}

    The following are the single Gaussian fits collected for this study, all, performed regardless of any asymmetries.

    \graphicspath{{SG/}}

    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=6cm]{singlegaussianfit_1.eps}
    \caption{Object 1}
    \end{figure}

    %%% And so on with my figures %%%
```

My preamble for the document is as follows:

```
    \documentclass{dmathesis}
    \date{}
    \usepackage{showlabel}
    \usepackage{longtable,lscape}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{wasysym}
    \usepackage[section]{placeins}
    \usepackage[maxfloats=110]{morefloats}
    \makeatletter\@openrightfalse\makeatother
    \usepackage{float}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

    \input{format}

    \includeonly{chapter1,chapter2,chapter3%
             ,chapter4,chapter5,chapter6,ref,append}


    \begin{document}


    \input{frontpage}

    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}

    \eqlabon
    \eqlaboff

    \include{chapter1}
    \include{chapter2}
    \include{chapter3}
    \include{chapter4}
    \include{ref}
    \include{append}
    \end{document}
```

I would appreciate and advice on how to fix this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  i'm not familiar with the document class you're using, but it looks like it defaults to `[twosided]`.  asymmetrical page layout is typical with that option, so i would have expected it on earlier pages as well, but we don't have any of those to compare.  and not related to the question, if options are passed to an underlying class, you might be able to specify `[openany]` rather than using the internal coding for `\@openrightfalse`,

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Judging from the posted images, this doesn’t look like the ordinary `twoside` asimmetry: note how the page following page 28 (which is not numbered 29: why?) is completely off-center.  To OP: does the compiler say anything bout `\deadcycles`?  (This looks like an “emergency” `\shipout`.)

Comment: Yes it does. Here is the message: "Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles. I've concluded that your \output is awry; it never does a \shippout, so I'm shipping \box255 out myself. Next time increase \maxdeadcycles if you want me to be more patient." So that seems to be the problem, but I'm not sure how to to increase \maxdeadcycles.

Comment: Never mind! I simply added \maxdeadcycles2000 to my preamble and fixed the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: OK, we are on the right track: now we have to understand what goes wrong during the output routine.  Does the problem arise in connection with figures with the `h` specifier?  Does it help if this specifier is changed to `tbp`?  Unfortunately, I cannot follow you anymore (it’s bedtime, for me! :-), but at least the experts that will come along now have a sound starting point to begin with.

Comment: I see that, in the meanwhile, you solved the problem by increasing `\maxdeadcycles`.  This means that no true infinite loop was actually involved.  But we are left with the curiosity (or, at least, I am) about the origin of the problem: by any chance, do you use a lot of floating figures?  (I saw that you load the _morefloats_ package.)  This _could_ be an explanation…

Comment: Yes, I do use a lot of floating figures, 100 per chapter for 3 chapters. morefloats was necessary for this, otherwise the document would start a new page after every 8 images or so, which ruined continuity.